# Webpage is not going to other pages after I used user authentication and logged in using react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

Webpage is not going to other pages after I used user authentication and logged in even i try changing the local page from http://localhost:3000/home to http://localhost:3000/ it just goes back to http://localhost:3000/home. I tried looking through the user auth but I cant seem to find the problem I am 99% sure this is where the problem resides.Only when I log out an change pages does it work but once Im logged in it doesn't

This error pops up on my homepage when I inspect
popup.ts:287 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
poll @ popup.ts:287
Show 1 more frame
Show less
popup.ts:287 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
poll @ popup.ts:287
Show 1 more frame
Show less
popup.ts:47 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.close call.
close @ popup.ts:47
Show 1 more frame
Show less
popup.ts:47 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.close call. this is a error message that pops up.

header.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  selectUserName,
  selectUserPhoto,
  setUserLoginDetails,
  setSignOutState,
} from "../features/user/userSlice";
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

const Header = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
  const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto);

  const setUser = useCallback(
    (user) => {
      dispatch(
        setUserLoginDetails({
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          photo: user.photoURL,
        })
      );
    },
    [dispatch]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        navigate("/home");
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [userName, setUser, navigate]); // Include setUser and navigate in the dependency array

  const handleAuth = () => {
    if (!userName) {
      // Attempt to sign in
      signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
          setUser(result.user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Consider using a more user-friendly way to display errors in production
          alert(error.message);
        });
    } else {
      // Attempt to sign out
      auth
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(setSignOutState());
          navigate("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Consider using a more user-friendly way to display errors in production
          alert(error.message);
        });
    }
  };

  // console.log(userPhoto);
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Logo>
        <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Disney+" />
      </Logo>
      {
        // If the user is logged in, display the user's photo and name
        !userName ? (
          <Login onClick={handleAuth}>Login</Login>
        ) : (
          <>
```

thia is my routing app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Detail from "./components/Detail";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/detail/:id" element={<Detail />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

so my app starts on login page its localhost:3000 then when i login in it takes me to the home page localhost:3000/home i use user authentication for the login with google accounts through firebase and when im on my home page if I try to go to another page it just takes me back to the home page eg: if i click on to a component that suppose to take me inro another page it doesnt it just goes for a second and takes me back to home page also if i type in website url eg: localhost:3000/detail it doensnt take me to that page. plz let me know if any more information is needed

Comment: How are you navigating through your app? After authenticating and getting navigated to `"/home"`, what exactly is happening next? Can you [edit] to clarify what the issue or problem is including the exact reproduction steps?

Comment: so my app starts on login page its  http://localhost:3000/ then when i login in it takes me to the home page  http://localhost:3000/home i use user authentication for the login with google accounts through firebase and when im on my home page if I try to go to another page it just takes me back to the home page eg: if i click on to a component that suppose to take me inro another page it doesnt it just goes for a second and takes me back to home page also if i type in website url eg: http://localhost:3000/detail it doensnt take me to that page. plz let me know if any more information is needed

Comment: So when on `"/home"`, *how* are you navigating to `"detail"`? Are you just changing the URL in the browser's address bar? I don't see any rendered links so I suspect this is what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your useEffect with one:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUser(user);
      // Only navigate to /home if the current path isn't already /home
      // This prevents unnecessary redirections if the user is already logged in
      if (window.location.pathname !== '/home') {
        navigate("/home");
      }
    }
  });

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, [setUser, navigate]); // Removed userName from dependencies to avoid redirection on every userName change
```